# Save 12-bit image (0-4095) to png file using openCV

Tags: opencv, camera, png, labview

I realize the openCV treat 12-bit image as u16, but align to the left most bits. Then if I just using imwrite with the raw data (lower 12-bit from a camera-GC660m), under windows 7, my image looks totally black. I guess the windows doesn't know my image has a dynamic range of 0-4095. I then use Labview image package to verify the data which is right, and save again to png. This time windows 7 can display my image with the correct range. So what I missed when using openCV?

Comment: Did you try multiplying all of the values by 16? (Or, equivalently, shifting them by 4 bits?)

Comment: yes, that's why I said opencv aligned the value to the left 12-bits (raw 12-bits * 16). My question would be how to save it in the original form (12 bits in U16 format but with dynamic range of  0-4095) in png and can be easily viewed by windows.

Comment: Sorry, I did misunderstand. So what does Labview change in the image that it can now be viewed correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I didn't make the question clear in the first place. After a little bit research, I found the answer on [Ni forums](https://forums.ni.com/t5/Machine-Vision/IMAQ-Write-PNG-rescaling-greyscale-images-bit-depth-after/td-p/345039). So in order for the png file to be viewed properly, the data (12-bit) is shifted to the leftmost of the full bit depth (16-bit), then fill the empty ones (right 4 bits) with the most significant bits. For example:

3144 = 0b 0000 **1100** 0100 1000 becomes 50316 = 0b **1100** 0100 1000 **1100**

All the three programs (Matlab, Labview and OpenCV) did this **left-replication** when write the image, but only Labview seem to utilize the **sBit** (significant bits) chunk of PNG format by default; thus correctly read the image value. The other two may need to do a bit-shift after loading.